# Server sent event - Stream is not reconnecting after few disconnections

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, server-sent-events, spring-kafka

I built a Spring boot application using this https://github.com/renatoaguimaraes/spring-reactive-kafka-sse.git while developing front end application I keep disconnecting and reconnecting SSE stream after a few successful reconnections I am getting below error and stream is not connecting automatically

```
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the 
software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1276)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:597)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:646)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.flush(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:169)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:252)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1564)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:352)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:118)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:121)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:103)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:43)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:224)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.send(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:189)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:189)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.send(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$SseEmitterSubscriber.send(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:341)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$AbstractEmitterSubscriber.run(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:283)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating EmitterProcesser set to autoCancel=false

```
private  EmitterProcessor<ServerSentEvent<String>> emitter = EmitterProcessor.create(false);
```